# Swift UITextField adjustFontSizeToFitWidth not functioning properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

I have been using a UITextField for the username and password fields of my application, and I noticed that when a username or password string is too big, it starts to eat away at the label next to it like so:

[image: screenshot of simulator where too long of a string will begin to cut off label text]

I have tested this by adding a border to my textfield and when the string is bigger than the width of the textField, the textField's border will expand left. Here is my `viewDidLoad:`

```
    usernameTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self
    usernameTextField.minimumFontSize = 6
    passwordTextField.minimumFontSize = 6
    usernameTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    passwordTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

These exact changes are also specified in the interface editor under the `Adjust To Fit` checkbox portion of the attributes inspector with a min font size of 6. I've been at this little glitch for a few hours and it's driving me nuts. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should post more information about your view hierarchy and any auto layout constraints you have.

Comment: Try with
self.passwordTextField.sizeToFit()
self.usernameTextField.sizeToFit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by just adding width constraints to the text field and the views next to it.